# Booting Linux From External USB Disk stops spinning

Tags: linux, boot, usb, external-hard-drive

I have installed Linux (Slackware 14.1) onto an external USB Disk on which I installed [LILO](http://lilo.alioth.debian.org).

The boot process starts correctly loading the kernel but, after a while, I got in a “kernel panic” error because Linux can’t mount root file system onto the USB drive. I added `rootdelay` option and `rootwait` option to the kernel command line and I can see the boot process stopping and then restarting with the same errors.

I have noticed that just after loading the kernel, the USB disk stops spinning and never starts again; so I guess this is the reason why the boot process cannot continue. How can I tell the kernel not to stops the usb disk from which it is booting?

Answer (score 0):

Reflash the USB or check that the USB itself is not damaged.

There really isn't much that could stop the LiveUSB from mounting it's own file system. It could be that in reality the error is in another part of the boot process but you only got to see that message.

So, without more info, I recommend to check that the USB that you are using is healthy and reflash the live usb image into it.